# JPA/SQL Server - Use list of Integers as Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot, t-sql, jpa

I have a list of Integer objects in my Spring Boot program that I want to use as a reference to update a table, only setting a column to a certain value for records with an id found in this list. Because of the potential length of the list, I want to avoid using the IN clause, as this will likely result in a SQL Server error for too many parameters.

The solution that I am thinking of involves a query similar to the following:

```
WITH ids as (select * from <list of Integers> as pool(num))
update t set t.column = :value from <table> t, ids where t.id = ids.num
```

The problem that I see with this is wrapping each Integer in the list in VALUE(), ie:

```
WITH ids as (select * from value(1),value(2),...etc)
```

While it seems that I could this query string programmatically by iterating over the list in Java, I would *really* like to avoid doing so if possible. I did try searching for a solution, but could not find quite what I was looking for. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing the query *anyway*, so I personally don't see an issue with constructing a values clause.  However, you can also parse a string:

```
update t
    set t.column = :value
    from <table> t,
   where t.id in (select * from string_split(@ids, ','));
```

Note:  You may need to be careful about type conversion, so if `id` is an integer:

```
update t
    set t.column = :value
    from <table> t,
   where t.id in (select try_convert(int, value) from string_split(@ids, ','));
```

Comment: If possible, I would like to avoid the IN clause, as having a long list for the IN can result in an error for too many parameters.

Comment: Not here it won't.  The problem you describe is only when the IN clause contains a list of values or parameters.  Here the IN clause has a subquery, and it's much more scalable.